# Windows Firewall Inbound and Outbound Rules Don't Work

Tags: windows, networking, internet, firewall, logitech-mouse

I have a programmable Logitech Mouse (G600), which requires installing Logitech software to program fully, and with Process Explorer I recently noticed that some "LCore.exe" file has a lot of network sends.  For example, after letting process explorer run for a few minutes, I see this (542 network sends):

[image]

All I use the software for is to program the extra buttons on the mouse, so it is completely unnecessary for it to have network access. So I created both inbound and outbound rules in the Windows Firewall (which is turned on) that is supposed to block LCore.exe on all network types (Public and Private) from sending or receiving information from the internet.

Specifically, for this file:
`C:\Program Files\Logitech Gaming Software\LCore.exe`
the action is to "block the connection" on Domain, Public, and Private profiles for both inbound and outbound.  However, after creating the firewall rule and restarting the computer, I checked process explorer to find:

[image]

So clearly it is still accessing the network, despite my firewall rules.  Can somebody explain why this is?  Am I not understanding how Windows firewall works, is Process Explorer wrong, or is Logitech finding some way around this?  **What do I need to do to fully stop this program from accessing the internet?**

Comment: The best method would be to identify the IP address the software is using and create a loopback entry within your hosts file.

Comment: Did you open the process in Process Explorer and confirm the program's attempts to connect are actually succeeding?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator, no, I didn't, primarily because I don't know how to confirm that. Would you explain how I can do that?

Comment: Double-click the process then look on the `TCP/IP` tab for any connections. If any are listed with a remote address other than `0.0.0.0` then the process is making connections successfully.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator, this is all I see when I view it that way.  I don't know what these dots mean: https://i.imgur.com/27T41hS.png

Comment: That means the process is listening for a remote connection but hasn't established one (there would be an IP address or hostname in the remote address column if a connection had been made.)